# I am facing error like,"Unhandled alert exception in selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

For 1 user 1 iteration code is working fine

When i go with 5 users and 5 iteration i am facing the Unhandled alert exception in webdriver sampler in Jmeter.

Could you please tell me how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

This will accept the alert, and handle the errors if there isn't one.

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    if (IsAlertPresent())
        driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
}

public bool IsAlertPresent()
{
    try
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.Instance.WindowHandles.LastOrDefault());
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```